# Making sense of a Lagrangian on a manifold

Tags: analysis, manifolds, riemannian-geometry

Going through Villani's book on Optimal Transport, I came across the following setup: a Riemannian manifold $M$ and a Lagrangian $L : TM \times [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ (So $L$ takes $(x, v, t)$ values as inputs). I'm wondering if I have the right notions of derivatives here. If $D_x L$ represents the spatial gradient, then we should have
$$
D_x L(x_0, v_0, t_0)(w) = \dot\gamma(0), 
$$
where $\tilde{\gamma}(0) = x_0, \dot{\tilde{\gamma}}(0) = w$, and $\gamma(t) = L(\gamma(t), v_0, t_0)$. Is this correct?

I'm a little more confused about the notion of $D_vL$, where this represents the velocity gradient. I have just defined as follows:
$$
D_v L(x_0, v_0, t_0)(w) = \dot\gamma(0),
$$
where $\gamma(t) = L(x_0, v_0 + tw, t_0)$, because this seems to make sense to me.

I was wondering if anyone could 1) let me know if these are correct, and (perhaps more importantly) 2) whether or not there is a better way of thinking about these objects.

Much appreciation for any help.

Comment: Ignore the time dependence for now, and just consider $L:TM\to\mathbb{R}$.  Treating $TM$ as its own manifold, for $\theta=(x,v)\in TM$, we have that $dL_\theta:T_\theta TM\to\mathbb{R}$.  You're trying to understand this as a decomposition of $T_\theta TM=H_\theta\oplus V_\theta$, as the horizontal and vertical spaces (since $M$ is Riemannian, these can be explicit).  I think Paternain's text "Geodeic Flows" has a brief exposition of this, which may be of benefit.  Unfortunately, I'm not very well versed in this either, but hopefully this helps some.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check out that reference. What do you mean by the "horizontal and vertical spaces"?